# Java - Correct way to declare a generic function?

Tags: java, generics

So long story short I have an object model in which several different entity types share a common supertype.  Any type derived from this supertype has an owning `User` associated with it, and I want to provide a generic utility function that can return all the entities of a given type belonging to a specified `User`.

All of that works fine, but my function declaration looks like:

```
public static <T> List<T> findByUser(Class<T> entityClass, User user, EntityManager em)
```

...and although this is accepted by the compiler, the syntax looks a little strange to me.  Is this the correct way to declare a function with a generic return type?  Ideally what I'd like to have is something more like:

```
public static List<T> findByUser(Class<T extends MySuperClass> entityClass, User user, EntityManager em)
```

But the compiler doesn't like that at all.  So my specific questions are:

1. Is there any way to get rid of the seemingly spurious `<T>` element after `static`?
2. What is the syntax that I need to use to make the compiler enforce that `T` must be derived from my superclass type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static <T extends MySuperClass> List<T> findByUser(Class<T> entityClass, User user, EntityManager em)
```

should work.

The `<T extends MySuperClass>` is needed in the method signature (after `static`) as that is where the bounds of the type `T` are being defined.

Answer (score 1):

the `<T>` after static tells the compiler that the function should be generic and allows you to set the constraints in it.

```
public static <T extends MySuperClass> List<T> findByUser(Class<T> entityClass, User user, EntityManager em)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
public static <T extends MySuperClass> List<T> findByUser(Class<T> entityClass, User user, EntityManager em)
```

The "spurious" `<T>` (or now `<T extends MySuperClass>`) is the *declaration* of the generic type parameter(s) used in the method signatures (return and parameter types).

Basically, the signature now says "calling this method always involves a class `T` that extends `MySuperClass`, and the first parameter must be a `Class` object that represents `T`, and the return type will be a `List<T>`.